# check if string contains only unique chars using .at(int)

Tags: c++

Really basic question but I can't figure this out.  My program checks if a string is unique by setting flags for each ASCII in an array to true if found in the string.  It's not working(it compiles, but doesn't give correct answer), and I can't for the life of my figure out why.

The output I get is 0:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.hpp"
#include <iostream>

bool isUnique(std::string str) {

    if(str.length() > 128)
        return false;

    bool theChars[128];

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int loc = str.at(i);

        if(theChars[loc])
            return false;
        else
            theChars[loc] = true;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {

    std::string timmy = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    std::cout << isUnique(timmy);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean for a string to be "unique"?

Comment: Non-static local variables are not automatically initialized, their values will be *indeterminate*. That include arrays and their elements.

Comment: @juanchopanza good point

Comment: From the code, it appears that "unique" means "length <= 128, numeric value of all characters in the range [0,127], and no character repeated".

Comment: Are you looking for [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) maybe?

Comment: @JesperJuhl if `std::unique` returns a Boolean, then yes, I am looking to implement that method

Comment: @defoification maybe start by *reading* the link.. and *if* it fits, why reimplement it rather than just *using* it?

Comment: @defoification well, the returned iterator - while *not* a `bool` - can trivially be turned into one by comparing to the previous `end()`; and if I read your question correctly (I may not) then that would actually match what you want..

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am implementing it for practice.  I'm a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the bool array:

```
bool theChars[128] = {};
```

The empty initializer means "use the default value" which is zero, aka false for bool.

P.S. Your code produces undefined behavior if you have any character outside [0, 127].  You could fix this by making `theChars` 256 long and casting the character to `uint8_t` before indexing.  Or use `std::array<char, 128>` and `theChars.at(loc)` to throw an exception if out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

easier way is use `set`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
bool isUnique(string str) {
    set<char>st(str.begin(),str.end());
    if(st.size()==str.size())
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {

    string timmy = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    cout << boolalpha<<isUnique(timmy)<<endl;
    timmy = "aaaaabbbcdefghijklmnop";
    cout << boolalpha<<isUnique(timmy)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

p.s. if not use `boolalpha`, it will print 1 for `true` and 0 for `false`.

Comment: Nice, that looks cleaner.  Is it still O(n) time and O(1) space?  I haven't used a set, but it looks that way

Comment: time - `N log(N)` where `N = std::distance(first, last)` in general, linear in N if the range is already sorted.  set and friends are usually implemented using some kind of self-balancing binary tree, so you are safe to assume that amount of memory required is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
return std::adjacent_find(str.begin(), str.end()) == str.end();
```

This doesn't use any additional space, and works for any character encoding.